# Best way to charge 750mAh in portable device

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

I know there are many posts on voltage regulators in battery powered applications but I hope to gain a better understanding of my specific problem.

The portable device I'm working on charges a li-ion device at 750mAh 500 mA (charging current) using disposable batteries. The solution needs to use consumer available batteries and the device will be used in a remote area without outlets so needing to charge is inconvenient. Also a small form factor is desirable. I only want to use a separate li-ion and rechargeable batteries if there's no other option to reduce complexity.

My first solution was using 4 aa batteries in series and a switching buck regulator to charge and power the components at VCC = 3.3V. I am aiming for 8 hours of use time. I know more measurements would help but I have none right now.

My plan is to have confidence in the approach and then take measurements and optimize. If anyone experienced could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's sounds like you're trying to more or less make a power bank that runs off of AA batteries. Does the device you want to charge have a built in charging circuit (I.E. a circuit that charges the batteries)?

Comment: Yes it has a built in charging circuit. The host has one sensor, an atmega328p operating at 3.3V 10Mhz, 8 LEDs and keeping the li-ion device charged enough to use. I plan on measuring the current consumption with a multimeter. Is 4 aa batteries a reasonable approach for 8 hour run time? Also I used the switching regulator to maintain efficiency but what do you think about keeping 2 batteries in parallel and using a boost regulator 3v -> 3.3v and gaining extra capacity?

Comment: Why doesn't it just run on the disposable batteries directly?

Comment: @user253751 because the li-ion isn't removable